# How many number of byes a python 3 string will take?

Tags: python-3.x

We know that in python 3, strings are Unicode strings. How many bytes a 3 character Unicode string takes in python 3?

Comment: Apparently it depends, https://rushter.com/blog/python-strings-and-memory/

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the individual characters themselves?